# Filtering Table data with useEffect Hook causing component to re-render infinitely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I'm trying to use a search bar component to dynamically filter the content of a table that's being populated by API requests, however when I use this implementation the component re-renders infinitely and repeatedly sends the same API requests.
The useEffect() Hook:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        const filteredRows = rows.filter((row) => {
            return row.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
        });
        if (filteredRows !== rows){
            setRows(filteredRows);
        }        
    }, [rows, search]);
```

Is there something I've missed in this implementation that would cause this to re-render infinitely?

Edit 1:
For further context, adding in relevant segments of code from that reference this component which might cause the same behaviour.

Function inside the parent component that renders the table which calls my API through a webHelpers library I wrote to ease API request use.

```
function fetchUsers() {
        webHelpers.get('/api/workers', environment, "api", token, (data: any) => {
            if (data == undefined || data == null || data.status != undefined) {
                console.log('bad fetch call');
            }
            else {
                setLoaded(true);   
                setUsers(data);
                console.log(users);
            }
        });
    }

    fetchUsers();
```

Edit 2:
Steps taken so far to attempt to fix this issue, edited the hook according to comments:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
        setRows((oldRows) => oldRows.filter((row) => {
            return row.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
        }));    
    }, [search]);
```

Edit 3:
Solution found, I've marked the answer by @Dharmik pointing out how Effect calls are managed as this caused me to investigate the parent components and find out what was causing the component to re-render repeatedly. As it turns out, there was a useEffect hook running repeatedly by a parent element which re-rendered the page and caused a loop of renders and API calls. My solution was to remove this hook and the sub-components continued rendering as they should without loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because you've added `rows` to `useEffect` dependency array and when someone enters something into `search bar`, The `rows` get filtered and `rows` are constantly updating.

And because of that `useEffect` is getting called again and again. Remove `rows` from the `useEffect` dependency array and it should work fine.

Comment: I've implemented this change, but I'm still having the same behaviour where my API requests are being repeatedly sent. Could a parent component cause this kind of behaviour too?

Comment: yes it can but I'm not sure what's going on in your code

Comment: Did you try the other answer?

Comment: Have implemented both of these answers now but I'm beginning to think this useEffect function isn't the issue causing the re-render. The Function now looks like this: 


`React.useEffect(() => {
        setRows((oldRows) => oldRows.filter((row) => {
            return row.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
        }));    
    }, [search]);`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to complement Dharmik answer. Dependencies should stay exhaustive (React team recomendation). I think a mistake is that `filteredRows !== rows` uses reference equality. But `rows.filter(...)` returns a new reference. So you can use some kind of deep equality check or in my opinion better somethink like:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        setRows((oldRows) => oldRows.filter((row) => {
            return row.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
        }));
    }, [search]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've added this to my implementation, but my problem remains. I've since edited the OP, the issue may be in the relation this component has to its parent component though I'm not sure.